# how to solve error "have subtitle controller already set"?

Tags: audio, flutter, audio-player

When I try to play the sound file in flutter it shows that "subtitle controller already set".
This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';


void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final player = AudioCache();
  static AudioCache playr = AudioCache();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){
              print('clicked');
              player.play('note2.wav');
            },color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('click me'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to solve this??

Comment: Did you search stackoverflow? There seems to be a several similar questions

Comment: @F-1 yes I serached, but didn't find any usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By updating the flutter sdk i solved this issue.